# Fullcalendar-scheduler view from 4am to 4am next day

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to get my fullcalendar timeline-day view to display from 4am to 4am the next day, I've currently set minTime to "04:00:00" but setting maxTime to "24:00:00" won't go past midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reported this on Github in [#112](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/112), which has been fixed in [v1.2.1](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/releases/tag/v1.2.1)